# Reading and choosing from an Excel validation list in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have an Excel spreadsheet - a lot of them actually - that have drop-down selections in them. I want to automate filling them in, selecting an option from the list.

When I inspect the cell that has the drop-down in Excel itself, I cannot click on Validation in the Data Tools ribbon section as it is greyed out. I think the sheet has protection.

When I inspect the cell in VBA, the `Validation.Formula1` property contains a string like `"=list_b1191f893baa0c18600db155cc008dd2_label"`.

How can I find the contents of this list in VBA so that I can pick one of the valid values?

Comment: I suspect there might be a hidden worksheet that contains a named range called `list_b1191f893baa0c18600db155cc008dd2_label`; try iterating the `ThisWorkbook.Names` collection (or use the Names manager from the Formula tab) and see what specific range of cells on what specific sheet that name is referring to. Actually you could probably just do `ThisWorkbook.Range("list_b1191f893baa0c18600db155cc008dd2_label").Value` to get a 2D variant array (probably with only 1 column, but still a 2D array) with all the values.

Comment: That said if you don't have the protection password, you shouldn't be expected to be able to maintain that workbook. First thing I'd do would be to try to crack that protection if nobody has the password for it.

Comment: Please try `Debug.print Range("list_b1191f893baa0c18600db155cc008dd2_label").Address(External:=True)`. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: Yes, there's a bunch of named ranges on a hidden worksheet. I didn't think there were any, as I thought that clicking on the "..." would bring up a list of worksheets if there were any hidden, clearly I've been doing far too much Google Docs recently! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list_b1191f893baa0c18600db155cc008dd2_label` would be a (presumably workbook-scoped) named range that you can pull into a `Range` variable like this:

```vb
Dim legalValuesSource As Range
Set legalValuesSource = ThisWorkbook.Names("list_b1191f893baa0c18600db155cc008dd2_label").RefersToRange
```

Or you can let Excel figure out what `Name` is being used here, by passing the name string to the `Range` function:

```vb
Dim legalValuesSource As Range
Set legalValuesSource = someSheet.Range("list_b1191f893baa0c18600db155cc008dd2_label")
```

Assuming that named range is *n* rows and 1 column (where *n* is greater than 1), you can pull the validation list values to an array like this (`Range.Value` yields a 2D variant array whenever it represents more than a single cell; `Transpose` should work to make it a single-dimensional array):

```vb
Dim legalValues As Variant
legalValues = Application.Transpose(legalValuesSource.Value)
```

Now you can pick any value from the `legalValues` array, and use it in the cell you pulled the validation list from:

```vb
thatCell.Value = legalValues(LBound(legalValues)) ' picks the first one that comes up
```

You can use any integer between `LBound(legalValues)` and `UBound(legalValues)` to pick a legal value.